# How to clone only simple property from an object to another?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object like this:

```
const obj = {
     "id": 5,
      "adress": "Test"
      "name": "Q1",
      "sections": [
            {
              "code": "S1",
              "label": "LS1",
              "subSections": [  //I can have this level, or not
                {
                  "code": "S1-1",
                  "label": 'LS1-1',
                  "questions": [ // If not, I will have this level instend
                    {
                      "code": "Q1",
                      "label": "LQ1",
                      "answer": [
                        {
                          "code": "A1",
                          "label": 'LA1',
                        }
                      ],
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
            }
      ]
}
```

I want to create a new obj but only with some simple propertys, without the array:

```
newObj = {
   "id": 5,
    "adress": "Test"
    "name": "Q1",
}
```

the challenge is to create the new object but in a dynamic form, so if a the first object change with a new property called Date, the new object has to be:

```
   const newObj = {
       "id": 5,
        "adress": "Test",
        "date": "somedate",
        "name": "Q1",
    }
```

Comment: And what did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid hardcoding the names of simple (or otherwise) properties, you can extract all entries of the current object, using `typeof` to filter out those whose values are not of simple data types, then create a new object from those entries.

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([prop, val]) => typeof(val) != 'object'))
```

Comment: dude, you Nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator, which will copy the whole object, and use the delete operator to remove part of the object you wish to remove.

```
const obj = {
"id": 5,
"adress": "Test",
"name": "Q1",
"sections": [
    {
        "code": "S1",
        "label": "LS1",
        "subSections": [  //I can have this level, or not
            {
                "code": "S1-1",
                "label": 'LS1-1',
                "questions": [ // If not, I will have this level instend
                    {
                        "code": "Q1",
                        "label": "LQ1",
                        "answer": [
                            {
                                "code": "A1",
                                "label": 'LA1',
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }
             ],
        }
        ]
        }

        const newObj = {...obj};

        delete newObj.sections;

        console.log(newObj); // {id: 5, address: 'Test', name: 'Q1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the object like so and omit the property you do not want. For example:

```js
const { sections, ...newObj } = obj;
```

This is by far the simplest method. It will create a variable called sections and put all the other properties into `newObj` however it's not usually considered good practice to create unused variables like that.

If you do not mind `undefined` values in your object for the `sections` property you could alternatively use `Object.assign()`:

```js
const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj, {
    sections: undefined
})
```

The final option would be to loop over the properties:

```
const newObj = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (key === 'sections') {
       continue;
    }

    newObj[key] = obj[key];
}
```

Do note, in all 3 of these examples you are only making a shallow copy of the object. Meaning, while the `newObj` is a new object the values inside if they are not primitive types (eg. string, number, boolean etc) they will refer to the same instance inside the `obj` object.